# Detecting when a specific block breaks [Spigot Plugin]

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to make a Spigot Plugin that lets you use a command such as `/copper` where you put in coordinates to the block and it summons armor stands to make it look like the block, that's how far I have gotten:

```
public class OreCommands implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("copper")) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int ypre = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                int y = ypre+1;
                double upy = y-1.75;
                double midy = y-2.25;
                double downy = y-2.8;
                double frontx = x+1;
                double backx = x-0.03125;
                double frontz = z+1;
                double backz = z-0.03125;
                    // up
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.AIR || player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.CAVE_AIR) {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "summon armor_stand " + x + " " + upy + " " + z + " {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\"minecraft:player_head\",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;420211400,-1836693680,-1895208571,1476527556],Properties:{textures:[{Value:\"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWM5Zjg5ZWUzNzE3ZTQ2OWMwY2QzNmMwM2MwZmQ2OWVjYjNiYTFkOWFiNTJhMmEwMWExMThiOGExYTc1NjcwYiJ9fX0=\"}]}}}}]}");
                    }
                    // down
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y-2, z).getType() == Material.AIR || player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.CAVE_AIR) {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "summon armor_stand " + x + " " + downy + " " + z + " {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\"minecraft:player_head\",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;420211400,-1836693680,-1895208571,1476527556],Properties:{textures:[{Value:\"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWM5Zjg5ZWUzNzE3ZTQ2OWMwY2QzNmMwM2MwZmQ2OWVjYjNiYTFkOWFiNTJhMmEwMWExMThiOGExYTc1NjcwYiJ9fX0=\"}]}}}}]}");
                    }
                    // north
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y-1, z-1).getType() == Material.AIR || player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.CAVE_AIR) {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "summon armor_stand " + x + " " + midy + " " + backz + " {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\"minecraft:player_head\",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;420211400,-1836693680,-1895208571,1476527556],Properties:{textures:[{Value:\"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWM5Zjg5ZWUzNzE3ZTQ2OWMwY2QzNmMwM2MwZmQ2OWVjYjNiYTFkOWFiNTJhMmEwMWExMThiOGExYTc1NjcwYiJ9fX0=\"}]}}}}]}");
                    }
                    // east
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x+1, y-1, z).getType() == Material.AIR || player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.CAVE_AIR) {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "summon armor_stand " + frontx + " " + midy + " " + z + " {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\"minecraft:player_head\",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;420211400,-1836693680,-1895208571,1476527556],Properties:{textures:[{Value:\"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWM5Zjg5ZWUzNzE3ZTQ2OWMwY2QzNmMwM2MwZmQ2OWVjYjNiYTFkOWFiNTJhMmEwMWExMThiOGExYTc1NjcwYiJ9fX0=\"}]}}}}]}");
                    }
                    // west
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x-1, y-1, z).getType() == Material.AIR || player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.CAVE_AIR) {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "summon armor_stand " + backx + " " + midy + " " + z + " {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\"minecraft:player_head\",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;420211400,-1836693680,-1895208571,1476527556],Properties:{textures:[{Value:\"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWM5Zjg5ZWUzNzE3ZTQ2OWMwY2QzNmMwM2MwZmQ2OWVjYjNiYTFkOWFiNTJhMmEwMWExMThiOGExYTc1NjcwYiJ9fX0=\"}]}}}}]}");
                    }
                    // south
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y-1, z+1).getType() == Material.AIR || player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.CAVE_AIR) {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "summon armor_stand " + x + " " + midy + " " + frontz + " {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\"minecraft:player_head\",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;420211400,-1836693680,-1895208571,1476527556],Properties:{textures:[{Value:\"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWM5Zjg5ZWUzNzE3ZTQ2OWMwY2QzNmMwM2MwZmQ2OWVjYjNiYTFkOWFiNTJhMmEwMWExMThiOGExYTc1NjcwYiJ9fX0=\"}]}}}}]}");
                    }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to detect when this block breaks and run some code such as summoning an item, killing the armor stands, etc. I have tried to use the `BlockBreak` event but it only lets you do stuff like cancel drop items and breaking, I want to get the person who broke the block and the coordinates of it but the event doesn't have functions for that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should spawn the armorstands programmatically using `world.spawnEntity(Location, EntityType`. This will return the armorstand entity so you can further configure it.

```java
ArmorStand armorstand = (ArmorStand) player.getWorld().spawnEntity(
                new Location(player.getWorld(), x, y, z), EntityType.ARMOR_STAND);
armorstand.setGravity(false);
armorstand.setInvisible(true);
armorstand.setBasePlate(false);
armorstand.getEquipment().setHelmet(headItemStack);
```

You can keep a reference to the armorstand somewhere along with which block it belongs to. To get the head ItemStack look [here](https://bukkit.org/threads/reflection-creating-skulls-with-non-player-skins.321991/).

On BlockBreak you simply check whether any of the armorstand entities you stored belonged to that block and remove those. To spawn the item use `world.dropItemNaturally(Location, ItemStack)`. It will summon an item with a random offset.

Comment: Everything works fine except for the head ItemStack, the thread was a bit outdated. I used [minecraft-heads.com](https://minecraft-heads.com/) to get the custom copper head for my armor stand if that helps.